# How can I delete Windows after installing Ubuntu via wubi?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

When I installed ubuntu from a CD the only option that seemed to work was to install within windows. Did I get a faulty version of ubuntu or am I doing something wrong? I'm able to select between windows and ubuntu when I turn on or reset, but I don't think that there is a real partition anywhere. GParted partition editor is only showing one partition that is being used and the rest as unallocated space. I'd like to get rid of windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-downloading the file, and using [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to install it from a flash drive. But first make sure your computer can boot from a USB device in the BIOS. Google instructions for your specific motherboard on how to do that. I always install from a flash drive and have never hadma problem. You can also use Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator* (search in dash) to make a bootable flash drive in Ubuntu.

*
Ubuntu

Insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space
Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator
Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app

Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file

Select the file and click 'Open'

Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'
That's it! When the process completes, you'll be ready to restart your computer and begin installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because you installed ubuntu inside windows

it is better to reinstall ubuntu alongside windows instead of installing via wubi

if you want current ubuntu files try remastersys to to get live dvd image of current system

Answer (score -1):

When Ubuntu installer asks for installation type, then select "erase disk and install ubuntu"
[image]

Comment: But be awared that you will loose your currently Ubuntu version.

Comment: It will erase your system 
must take backup of important data